# How can I make a UIButton get a function when I touch outside the button and drag over the button?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

If I had a label and a button If i touch outside the button and swiped over the button then an event should be fired to display "hello" in the label field. tell me how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Please do following steps.

1. Take UILabel and UIButton in your XIB file.
2. Take UILabel and UIButton as IBOutlet in your ViewController's .h file and take property of this two described below.

   ```
     UILabel *lbl;
     UIButton *btn;
     @property(nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UILabel *lbl;
     @property(nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UIButton *btn;
   ```
3. Now set UILabel and UIButton's New Reference outlet from XIB and set UIButton's TouchUpInside link to btnClicked method.
4. Declare this method in your .h file and implement it in your .m file for button event.
   Write this in your .h file

   ```
    -(IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender;
   ```

   and place this code in your .m file

   ```
    -(IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender
    {
         lbl.text = @"Hello";
    }
   ```

Comment: I am asking not about clicking, its about touching outside the button and drag over the button. help me about this

Answer (score 0):

This is simple...

```
UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect]; // init a button 

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonDraggedOrTouchedOutSide:) 
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragEnter|UIControlEventTouchDragInside
 |UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];

[self.view addSubview:button]; // add button to view



-(void)buttonDraggedOrTouchedOutSide:(id)sender {
    //Do your stuff
}
```

Thats it..Now you can catch drag and touch outside events...

Comment: Its not about touching the button. only to move over the button from outside.

Comment: It can handle outside movement... Did you try this out?